# Support portrait in iOs except for one view controlelr

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an iOs project that needs to support all orientations on iPad and on iPhone I need to support only portrait on all view controllers EXCEPT one that needs to support all orientations and autorotate.

I tried:

```
#pragma mark - Should Rotate device
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([[DeviceInfo sharedInstance] is_iPhone]) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
}
```

But that method doesn't get called... 
How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is right then I have given answer for this query so u could follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865142/possibility-portrait-mode-in-1-uiview/25865389?noredirect=1#comment40474365_25865389).

Do let me know if any doubt.

Okay so got solution for your iOS 7 as below method write down in appDelegate class.

```
- (NSUInteger) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {

  if ([[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] childViewControllers] lastObject] isKindOfClass:[ViewController class]])   //Here you could provide your view controller and provide orientation which u want for that particular view controller.
  {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
  }
  else
  {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
  }
}
```

This will help you out for iOS 7.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I implemented the methods. But they don't get called at all.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you select the wanted ones here:

[image]

Select your app in project navigator -> general -> select your target -> scroll down to deployment info.

Comment: I need only one view controller to autorotate

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by implementing the methods on the navigation controller that owns all the views