# iOS app can support landscape orientation for only one tabBar item?

Tags: ios, swift

I’m making iOS application using swift. My app has many view and all view has UITabBar as root view. I need to support landscape orientation for only one tabbar item.

- tabBar 1 - Portrait only
- tabBar 2 - Portrait only
- tabBar 3 - Portrait only
- tabBar 4 - Landscape & Portrait

How can i do that?

Comment: Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25925127/5066675

Comment: This could be simpler to implement. It seems like a similar problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651969/setting-device-orientation-in-swift-ios

Comment: Okay I will manage orientation per view But I have a question. When my app are current landscape mode in tabBar 4. when I move to another tabBar my app not back to portrait mode. Should I check per view and force rotation, right ?

ps.sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 2):

I have a working solution based on this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24928474/1359306

1. So first off, make sure the supported orientations are checked in `Target Settings > General > Deployment Info`.

[image: Target Settings > General > Deployment Info]

2. Add this code (taken from the linked answer) to your app delegate:

   ```
   internal var shouldRotate = false
   func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
     if shouldRotate {
       return .AllButUpsideDown
     } else {
       return .Portrait
     }
   }
   ```
3. Then in your landscape only view controller, put the following code in `viewDidAppear` (NOT viewDidLoad!) to enable both portrait and landscape view:

   ```
   let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
   appDelegate.shouldRotate = true
   ```
4. And the opposite to `viewWillDisappear` to disable landscape again.

   ```
   let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
   appDelegate.shouldRotate = false
   ```
5. I am also hiding my tabs and status bar when the app is in landscape, which feels like a much better UX than tapping a tab and automatically rotating the screen.

---

There are a few things which in my case I don't have to worry about.

- Displaying a modal view from a landscape view would cause issues

Comment: A votedown with no comment :/ If this answer is wrong or can be improved then comment. I have this code in prod.